# Seeking general proof of solution to "Shoemaker"

Tags: algorithm

I came across this problem:

> A shoemaker has N jobs (orders from customers) to execute.
>
> The shoemaker can work on only one job each day. For each job i, T[i]
>   (1≤T[i]≤1000) is the time in days it takes the shoemaker to finish the
>   job. For each day of delay before starting to work on job i, the
>   shoemaker must pay a fine of S[i] cents (1≤S[i]≤10000). Your task is
>   to help the shoemaker to find the sequence of jobs with minimal total
>   fine.

The solution simply says:

> Sort by S[i]/T[i]. Do not use float!

Could somebody elaborate on the solution? I get that we have to do jobs with low T and high S first and I see how for some inputs this would work, but could somebody demonstrate that sorting by S[i]/T[i] works in the general case?

Comment: "Do not use float!" Given the limits, the 64-bit variety would be fine.

Answer (score 3):

The proof looks like this: let's assume that the order of jobs is fixed somehow. Let's take a look at two adjacent jobs. If we swap them, the answer for the jobs before these two and after these two does not change. So we can ignore all other jobs and see what happens if we swap these two as if there we no others. If they are not swapped, the fine is `f1 = s1 * t1 + (t1 + t2) * s2`. If they are swapped, it is `f2 = s2 * t2 + s1 * (t1 + t2)`. In an optimal answer `f1 <= f2`, which means `s2 * t1 <= s1 * t2`, or `s1 / t1 >= s2 / t2`. This comparator is transitive, so an optimal local ordering gives an optimal global answer.

Answer (score 0):

Assume by contradiction that it exists an ordering that is optimal and it is not ordered by S[i]/T[i]. 
=> It exists a couple of of jobs i and j such that S[i]/T[i] > S[j]/T[j] and j is executed before i.

Consider how the total fine would change by switching the order of i and j, an get a contradiction with the original assumption that such ordering was optimal.

Is this enough or do you need me to complete the argument/elaborate?